# Windows Crash After Connecting Iphone To Xcode 12 On A VM

Tags: vmware, xcode, macos-catalina

I'm actually developping on a vmware of MacOS Catalina 10.15.5 with Xcode 12. I want to test my app on a physical phone so I connect my iphone to the VM with no problem but when i want to connect it to xcode, I get a blue screen of windows 10. I don't understand why and I have search everywhere a solution without finding anything so if someone have an idea to help me, I take it.

If you need any other information, just ask and I would answer you.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the use of macOS on non-Apple hardware is a legal grey area and as a result "Hackintosh" questions have been deemed [off-topic](http://meta.superuser.com/questions/1471/are-hackintosh-questions-allowed).

Comment: macOS is not licensed for your machine, therefore there are no official drivers for your hardware nor any official additions for your VM. Any diagnosis would require intimate knowledge of the hardware you do have & sources of unofficial drivers for it.